# hidden browse button is messing up my table

Tags: html, css, forms, button, menu

I am trying to make a floating menu that sticks to the top of the screen and has a few icons you can click, most of which will submit a form.  As it stands though, the filechoosebutton is hidden via css, but even though it is not rendering, it still causes my download button to disappear offscreen.  How can I fix this?

Thanks for any clues

---

Here is the html for the menu

```
<div id='floating_menu'>
    <table >
        <tr>
            <td >
                <form action='' method='post' id='trash1' >
                    <img src='http://s27.postimg.org/jua3mu9q9/trash.jpg' width="35" height="45" alt='delete' />
                </form>
            </td>
            <td >
                <img id='storagebutton' src='http://i60.tinypic.com/2igya9d.jpg' width="35" height="45" alt='storage' />
            </td>
            <td >
                <form id="uploadtsvform" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="">
                    <input id="filechoosebutton" name="uploadFile" type="file" onchange="this.form.submit()" />
                    <img id='uploadbutton' onClick='chooseFile()' src='http://oi59.tinypic.com/2lm0yky.jpg' width="35" height="45" alt='upload tsv' />
                </form>
            </td>
            <td >
                <img id='downloadbutton' src='http://i62.tinypic.com/zu4n03.jpg' width="35" height="45" alt='download tsv' />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Here is the css that creates the floating menu

```
#floating_menu {
    background:white;
    width:250px;
    height:25px;
    position:fixed;
    top:10px;
    right:0;
}
```

Here is the css that hides the usual Browse upload button

```
#filechoosebutton {
    height:0px;
    width:0px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/slashdottir/cQj54/5/)

Comment: Consider `display: none;` instead of `overflow: hidden;`.

Answer (score 0):

You form is eating up the space of the download button. Try adding

```
#uploadtsvform {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
}
```